# Why is this method available in this trait?

Tags: php, inheritance, traits

I am looking to extend a trait by using it in another trait. However the trait is using a method that looks like it isn't extending. The trait works, so I am wondering how.

Why does this trait have access to the `markEntityForCleanup` method?

The code is in this [repo for Drupal Test Traits](https://gitlab.com/weitzman/drupal-test-traits)

```php
<?php

namespace weitzman\DrupalTestTraits\Entity;

use Drupal\Tests\node\Traits\NodeCreationTrait as CoreNodeCreationTrait;

/**
 * Wraps the node creation trait to track entities for deletion.
 */
trait NodeCreationTrait
{

    use CoreNodeCreationTrait {
        createNode as coreCreateNode;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a node and marks it for automatic cleanup.
     *
     * @param array $settings
     * @return \Drupal\node\NodeInterface
     */
    protected function createNode(array $settings = [])
    {
        $entity = $this->coreCreateNode($settings);
        $this->markEntityForCleanup($entity);
        return $entity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

When using the Drupal Test Traits package you are expected to use your own custom php-unit `bootstrap.php` and [manually load the required packages](https://gitlab.com/weitzman/drupal-test-traits/blob/master/src/bootstrap-fast.php#L23).

Adding this line to the bottom of the bootstrap script will gain access to the namespace in php.

```php
// <?php is needed for SO to do the syntax highlighting.
<?php

// Register more namespaces, as needed.
$class_loader->addPsr4('weitzman\DrupalTestTraits\Entity\\', "$root/vendor/weitzman\drupal-test-triats\src\Entity");
```